# Why does height look so different on IE11?

Tags: css

I have an svg object with `width: 200px` and `height: auto`. on (almost) every browser (edge, firefox, opera - all updated), the height seems to be as expected - `60.27px`, calculated by browser. But IE11... makes my life harder (I can't say it was surprising). See the differences:

[image: IE11 height: auto, Opera 58.0 height: auto and ff 66.0 height: auto]

svg code:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 162.229 48.884" enable-background="new 0 0 162.229 48.884" xml:space="preserve">
        <rect fill="#111111" width="162.229" height="48.884"/>
    </svg>
```

css:

```
._logo svg {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

(`._logo` contains `box-sizing: border-box`)

Why is this happening?

Comment: BTW, Excuse my english

Comment: Can you post the svg code?

Comment: Are you using `box-sizing: border-box;`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes

Comment: @gwar9 updated^

Comment: @CertainPerformance i've undeleted my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in IE where it doesn't scale the SVG properly if you don't provide both the width and height. You may want to try to set the height if you can. Or you can try the Canvas way. http://nicolasgallagher.com/canvas-fix-svg-scaling-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly set the `height` on the svg. Right now you are using `height: auto`. The reason why the svg loses it's aspect ratio in IE is because in that browser height is calculated from from the root rather than the wrapping element as you may be expecting. If you want the height of the svg to be 60px I would just set that.

Comment: but the whole point is that browser will define height... I found the 60px height thanks to firefox & opera (that's how they defined it)

Comment: You asked why I told you why. This is long known issue with ie. It's a gotcha that you work around.